# Upgrading yarn in root directory do not upgrade Workspace dependencies

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, lerna, yarn-workspaces

On running `yarn upgrade` in root directory, it is upgrading only root directory's `package.json` and `yarn.lock`, but I need to upgrade `workspace dependencied`.

Is there a way to do so, other than using `yarn upgrade-interactive`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found an alternative

```
yarn workspace (workspace name) add (package name) (type of dependancy)
```

for all the packages you need to upgrade.

Then

```
yarn install
```

Comment: Is it possible to upgrade a package, say `typescript` at once in all *workspaces*?

Answer (score 4):

## Option a) Chain two commands

You can chain two commands together:

```
yarn upgrade -W && yarn workspace <workspace> upgrade
```

or to upgrade a specific package:

```
yarn upgrade <package> -W && yarn workspace <workspace> upgrade <package>
```

## Option b) Create a function

Act on the root and each workspace in one command.

For many workspaces, or if you don't want to write the package name twice, you can automate this with a function.

Requirements: You will need [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) installed.

Enter this line once per shell session:

```
yarn_all() { yarn -W $@ && for w in $(yarn -s workspaces info | jq -r 'keys[]'); do yarn workspace $w $@; done; }
```

Usage: `yarn_all <command> [<package>]`

### Examples:

```
yarn_all upgrade
```

```
yarn_all upgrade my-package
```

```
yarn_all upgrade my-package --registry http://localhost:4873
```

It can be used with other commands as well, such as `remove`.

Tested with `yarn` v1.22.4 and `jq` v1.6

Comment: `sed '1d;$d'` removes the first and the last line of the output of `yarn workspaces info`. They contain metadata added by Yarn (yarn version and the execution time). Yarn can be told to not add the metadata by using the `-s` option, that you already have in the command line but Yarn ignores it. The `-s` option should stay before the Yarn command, like this: `yarn -s workspaces info`. This way `| sed '1d;$d'` is not needed and the command is more robust to changes in the Yarn output.

Comment: Thank you @axiac - I've edited the code.
Not tested - I trust you! :)

Answer (score 3):

This is handled much better in yarn version 2. 
There you can do

```
yarn up react react-dom
```

And it will be aware of workspaces, or add `-i` for interactive mode, where it will ask you what to do for each dependency upgrade in each workspace.

Comment: I use yarn v1, and aint read that 10 mile long Migration Documentation just to run `yarn up`.